# how protect open text file against writing in java

Tags: java, file

I tried to protect open txt file against writing. I found methods canRead() and canWrite() but they are not useful in my code. After closing file, changes unfortunatelly have been done.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
private void filesMethod(String directoryName, String fileExtension, String textFind, String textSet)
    {
        File file = new File(directoryName);
        File[] foundFiles = file.listFiles();

        if(foundFiles != null)
        {
            for(File f : foundFiles)
            {
                if(f.isFile())
                {   

                                    if(!f.canRead()) 
                                    {
                                     continue;
                                    }
                                    ...             

                }               
                else if(f.isDirectory())
                    filesMethod(f.getAbsolutePath(), fileExtension, textFind, textSet);
            }   
        }       
    }
```

If file is open, method canRead() returns TRUE, but I am searching some method which returns false in this case...

Comment: What do you mean by "changes unfortunatelly have been done"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: when file is open I would like not to change it

Comment: Are you looking for a [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)?

Comment: This is going to be pretty tough to do in order to make it work across different platforms. You're getting into OS specific commands here.

Comment: See if the [following](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DemonstratesfilelockingandsimplefilereadandwriteoperationsusingjavaniochannelsFileChannel.htm) helps any.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your user's read privileges from the file, but that would be problematic (if your program crashes before you restore them, your users can complain).

A more common way of addressing this is to lock the file when you open it, that way you make sure the file can't be opened again until you close it (and if your program crashes, the OS releases the lock for you).

Answer (score 0):

(a) Are you aware that locking the file won't keep other processes from touching it unless they
also use locks?
(b) You have to lock via a writable channel. Get the lock via a RandomAccessFile in "rw"
mode and then open your FileInputStream . Make sure to close both!